# How do I create an object that is compatible with the Timestamp type in protobuf.js in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

When I try to assign to a Timestamp field of a protocol buffer built with protobuf.js, I get a TypeScript error.

My protocol buffer has the following definition:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message MyMessage {
    Timestamp expires_at = 1;
}
```

My Typescript file is the following:

```js
import { MyMessage } from ...
import { Timestamp } from 'google-protobuf/google/protobuf/timestamp_pb.js'

export const myFunction() {
    let myMessage = new MyMessage()
    myMessage.expiresAt = new Timestamp()
}
```

I get an error messsage that says: `Type 'Timestamp' has no properties in common with type 'ITimestamp'`

What's going on here? What is `ITimestamp`? How do I create an object that is compatible with the Timestamp type in protobuf.js?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the JavaScript Protobuf SDKs but (a) `protobuf.js` doesn't include `google.protobuf.timestamp` see this [issue](https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/pull/1258#issuecomment-953476331); (b) your code mixes 2 incompatible libraries [protobuf.js](https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/) and [protobuf-javascript](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-javascript). Wow JavaScript|npm is complicated.... GitHub `protobuf.js` --> npm `protobufjs` (no period because there's a different npm package `protobuf.js`) and GitHub `protobuf-javascript` is npm `google-protobuf`!!